Trying to generate a packing list based on certain stock codes
So I am fairly new to app script. I work for a manufacturing company that has a production schedule which includes things such as sales order numbers, customer name, location, work order numbers, stock codes, a general description of the stock codes. These stock codes for the most part generally have the same small parts that go together to fulfill a job. I would love to have a way to copy and paste lines from this schedule into a sheet or some other area and have it make a sheet that pulls information from the stock codes to generate a packing list and/or a bill of lading for delivery. I have begun to compile a list of stock codes that have a list of parts tied to it.
For example:
I have a master key sheet that includes something like this



STOCK CODE
PART A
QTY
PART B
QTY
ETC




1WBR-CLB-AB
1/2-13X42 ANCHOR BOLTS
16
CLB TEMPLATES
4




Then I have a 'mastery query' sheet that has a column where numerous stock codes can be entered. Every time a stock code is entered it generates the associated stock code from the 'master key' sheet and organizes the items in Part A into column A of the 'master query' sheet and multiplies the quantity based on the number entered next to the stock code.
For example:
PARTS LIST QUANTITY



STOCK CODE
QTY




1/2-13x42 ANCHOR BOLTS
32


1WBR-CLB-AB
2


CLB TEMPLATES
8



The problem I am running into is that in the 'master query' sheet I had to make 22 rows available per stock code entry in the parts list to account for the total number of parts for every stock code. (So that if I had 5 of stock codes that had 22 parts or less there would be a row for each of the columns listed in the 'master key' sheet) I discovered a way to automatically hide rows that were showing no parts or no quantity. And as long as my 22 part stock code comes first it works for the most part. If its not the longest in the list, it cuts off the list of stock codes even though the list still generates correctly in column a and b.
There has to better way. Ideally I would love to be able to copy and paste information directly from our production schedule into a sheet and then make a script that could automatically take the information i copy and paste and add the missing parts information directly into a list that could be used for packaging and shipping of the product. Here is an example of a production schedule.



REQ SHIP
WO#
CUSTOMER
LOCATION
STOCK CODE
BRIEF   DESCRIPTION
QTY
SO#




07/1/2024
115704
TACO TOWN
HOUSTON, TX
1WBR-CLB-AB
CLBAR ANCHOR BOLTS
2
26354



I would love to be able to auto generate a packing list for my packaging team to pull all of the parts necessary in a compiled list from several stock codes that could be generated from a trigger in the stock code and add information such as location and sales order in appropriate places automatically. I would even be fine with being able to paste 10 rows from our production schedule into a sheet and run a script that would generate this information in the same format as the schedule in a row under each stock code until all of the parts were listed.
I am reaching out as a person eager to learn app script. I know a few things but I grew up on html. Javascript type language I never dived into much. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much,
Chad
I do have one basic sheet that I have been playing with but I am definitely open to other options

Would you please double check for formatting of your data tables.

Is this requirement what we generally describe as a "bill of materials"?

FWIW, I would structure the “Master Key ” sheet vertically (just three columns-ColA=Parent part code, ColB = child part code, ColC= Child code qty.) rather than horizontally. It provides more consistent structure and simplifies analysis and reporting.

I would suggest you look into Simple and Installable Triggers in Apps Script link. You could use the onEdit(e) function to handle changes in your spreadsheet, say when you copy a Stock Code from the master query sheet to your bill of materials. You should also brush up on some basic JavaScript and lots of ways to manipulate Arrays.

You are trying to automate the creation of a packing slip based on certain stock codes. These codes are driven by a work order for the production of certain products which is, in turn, driven by a sales order.
There are many ways of doing this; a script is NOT required. The only downside to the non-script approach is that borders can't be automatically made on the Packing slip.
Comments on this script, and data

An Installable onEdit() trigger should be created for the script
The script is triggered by a checking a checkbox on the Production Schedule (refer image). This will populate the Pickling slip based on the infomation
This version of the script assumes only one item on the Production schedule (in cell E3), but the script can be easily extended to cater for multiple products.
The script assumes a layout of the "Master" sheet that is different to the OP. (refer the image). This vertical layout is much more efficient than the proposed horizontal layout.


function buildPickSlip(e) {
  
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // create variables for watching for picking slip check
  var sheet2Watch = "Production Schedule"
  var col2Watch = 9
  var row2Watch = 2 // header row
  
  // test for correct sheet, column, row and value
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !== sheet2Watch){
    // no match on sheet, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: No Match on sheet")
    return
  }
  else if (e.range.columnStart !== col2Watch || e.range.rowStart <= row2Watch || e.value !== "TRUE"){
    // no match on column, row or checked checkbox, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: No match on column or row or checkbox value")
    return
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet:"+e.range.getSheet().getName()+", column:"+e.range.columnStart+", row:"+e.range.rowStart+", value:"+e.value)

  // get the product code and production quantity from the production order
  var prodSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet2Watch)
  var productCode = prodSheet.getRange("E3").getValue()
  var productQty = prodSheet.getRange("G3").getValue()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: PRODUCTION SCHEDULE: Product Code = "+productCode+", and product qty = "+productQty)


  // get the products from the Master sheet
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master")
  var masterLR = masterSheet.getLastRow()
  // get the data; not started at row 2 to avoid headers
  var masterData = masterSheet.getRange(2,1,masterLR-1,3).getValues()
  // Logger.log(masterData) // DEBUG


  // create a temporary array to hold the picking slip values
  var pickArray = []
  // loop through the Master sheet and find matches for the productCode from the Production Schedule
  for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++){ 
    if (masterData[i][0] === productCode){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", product code = "+productCode+", child code:"+masterData[i][1]+", child qty:"+masterData[i][2])
      pickArray.push([masterData[i][1],masterData[i][2]])
    }
  }
  // Logger.log(pickArray) // DEBUG

  // paste values to Picking Slip
  // top left corner = cell A6
  var pickSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Picking Slip1")
  // clear the existing content and unset existing borders
  pickSheet.getRange(6,1,pickSheet.getMaxRows()-6,2).clear()

  // define the new range
  var pickRange = pickSheet.getRange(6,1,pickArray.length,2)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Range: "+pickRange.getA1Notation())
  pickRange.setValues(pickArray)
  // set borders
  pickRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  
}


Production schedule

Master sheet

Picking Slip


Interesting. I like the way you have that layout way better than what I had. I think I will try to use that as a base template and customize from there. I really appreciate the advice

Is there a way to have the ability to compile a single list from like 5 stock codes that are in one sales order on the production schedule. For example if a sales order contained Parent Part Code 1WBR-CLB-AB and ABC-DEF as well as any others. Would it be possible to generate one list for picking?

Is there a way to have the ability to compile a single list from like 5 stock codes that are in one sales order on the production schedule. Refer the second answer.

You are trying to automate the creation of a packing slip based on certain stock codes. These codes are driven by a work order for the production of certain products which is, in turn, driven by a sales order.
This answer assumes that the Production Schedule includes several products.

/*
// caters for multiple items on the Production Schedule
*/

function buildPickSlip(e) {
  
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // create variables for watching for picking slip check
  var sheet2Watch = "Production Schedule"
  var col2Watch = 9
  var row2Watch = 2 // header row
  
  // test for correct sheet, column, row and value
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !== sheet2Watch){
    // no match on sheet, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: No Match on sheet")
    return
  }
  else if (e.range.columnStart !== col2Watch || e.range.rowStart <= row2Watch || e.value !== "TRUE"){
    // no match on column, row or checked checkbox, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: No match on column or row or checkbox value")
    return
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet:"+e.range.getSheet().getName()+", column:"+e.range.columnStart+", row:"+e.range.rowStart+", value:"+e.value)

  // get the product code and production quantity from the production order
  var prodSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet2Watch)
  var prodSheetFR = 3
  var prodSheetLR = prodSheet.getLastRow()
  var productCodeCol = 5// Column E
  var productQty = 7// Column G
  var prodScheduleItems = prodSheet.getRange(3,productCodeCol,prodSheetLR-prodSheetFR+1,3).getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG PROD SCHEDULE Range = "+prodSheet.getRange(3,productCodeCol,prodSheetLR-prodSheetFR+1,3).getA1Notation())
  // Logger.log(prodScheduleItems) // DEBUG
  var wOrder = prodSheet.getRange("B3").getValue()

  // get the products from the Master sheet
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master")
  var masterLR = masterSheet.getLastRow()
  // get the data; not started at row 2 to avoid headers
  var masterData = masterSheet.getRange(2,1,masterLR-1,3).getValues()
  // Logger.log(masterData) // DEBUG


  // create a temporary array to hold the picking slip values
  var pickProdArray = []
  var pickPartArray = []
  // loop through the Master sheet and find matches for the productCode from the Production Schedule
  for (var j=0;j<prodScheduleItems.length;j++){
    pickProdArray.push([prodScheduleItems[j][0],prodScheduleItems[j][2]])
    for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++){ 
      if (masterData[i][0] === prodScheduleItems[j][0]){
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", product code = "+prodScheduleItems[j][0]+", qty: "+prodScheduleItems[j][2]+", child code:"+masterData[i][1]+", child qty:"+masterData[i][2])
        pickPartArray.push([masterData[i][1],masterData[i][2]*prodScheduleItems[j][2]])
      }
    }
  }
  //Logger.log(pickProdArray) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log(pickPartArray) // DEBUG

  // create some variables for the Picking slip
  // Products - A5; Picking Slip - D5
  var pickSlipStartRow = 5
  var pickProdStartCol = 1 //A
  var pickPartStartCol = 4// D
  var pickSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Picking Slip1")

  // paste the Work order to the Picking Slip
  pickSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(wOrder)

  // clear the existing content and unset existing borders
  pickSheet.getRange(pickSlipStartRow,pickProdStartCol,pickSheet.getMaxRows()-pickSlipStartRow+1,2).clear()

  // define the Picking Slip Products Range
  var pickProdRange = pickSheet.getRange(pickSlipStartRow,pickProdStartCol,pickProdArray.length,2)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Products Range: "+pickProdRange.getA1Notation())
  pickProdRange.setValues(pickProdArray)
  // set borders
  pickProdRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  
  // define the Picking Slip Parts Range
  var pickPartsRange = pickSheet.getRange(pickSlipStartRow,pickPartStartCol,pickPartArray.length,2)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Parts Range: "+pickPartsRange.getA1Notation())
  pickPartsRange.setValues(pickPartArray)
  // set borders
  pickPartsRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
}


Production Schedule


Picking Skip


Master

